# How can i add toggle to my this html code

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggle

I have written some html and css code to show a faq page question and answer, but I want to give it a toggle effect. When you click on the question it should open the answer section of that particular question.
Here is the html code:

```
<div id="faq_content">
   <div class="title">
      <strong>FAQs</strong><br>
   </div>
   <div class="answer_visible">
      <div type="button" class="q_button" onclick="">
         <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit? </span> 
         <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>                 
         <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>                   
      </div>
      <div class="answer">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="answer_hidden">
      <div type="button" class="q_button" onclick="">
         <span>Consectetur adipiscing elit? </span> 
         <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>                 
         <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>                   
      </div>
      <div class="answer">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="answer_hidden">
      <div type="button" class="q_button" onclick="">
         <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit? </span> 
         <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>                 
         <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>                   
      </div>
      <div class="answer">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="answer_hidden">
      <div type="button" class="q_button" onclick="">
         <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit? </span> 
         <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>                 
         <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>                   
      </div>
      <div class="answer">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="answer_hidden">
      <div type="button" class="q_button" onclick="">
         <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit? </span> 
         <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>                 
         <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>                   
      </div>
      <div class="answer">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="answer_hidden">
      <div type="button" class="q_button" onclick="">
         <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet? </span> 
         <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>                 
         <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>                   
      </div>
      <div class="answer">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="answer_hidden">
      <div type="button" class="q_button" onclick="">
         <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit? </span> 
         <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>                 
         <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>                   
      </div>
      <div class="answer">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="answer_hidden">
      <div type="button" class="q_button" onclick="">
         <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit? </span> 
         <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>                 
         <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>                   
      </div>
      <div class="answer">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="answer_hidden">
      <div type="button" class="q_button" onclick="">
         <span>Consectetur adipiscing elit? </span> 
         <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>                 
         <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>                   
      </div>
      <div class="answer">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="answer_hidden">
      <div type="button" class="q_button" onclick="">
         <span> consectetur adipiscing elit? </span> 
         <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>                 
         <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>                   
      </div>
      <div class="answer">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="answer_hidden">
      <div type="button" class="q_button" onclick="">
         <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit? </span> 
         <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>                 
         <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>                   
      </div>
      <div class="answer">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="answer_hidden">
      <div type="button" class="q_button" onclick="">
         <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit? </span> 
         <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>                 
         <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>                   
      </div>
      <div class="answer">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="answer_hidden">
      <div type="button" class="q_button" onclick="">
         <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit? </span> 
         <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>                 
         <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>                   
      </div>
      <div class="answer">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added css and its look like this at present http://prntscr.com/8tkubj

Comment: Can you add CSS too in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
I added this jquery code and its working great

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery(".answer_hidden").click(function(){
 jQuery(this).find(".answer").toggle();
 jQuery(this).toggleClass("answer_visible");

       });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `display` of answer class to `none`. Now we need to display the answer when user clicks on an element with class `fa-angle-down` and hide the same when the user clicks on an element with the class `fa-angle-up`. Here is the jQuery solution.

```
$('.fa-angle-down').click(function(){ 
  $(this).parent().parent().find('.answer').hide();
});

$('.fa-angle-up').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().find('.answer').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery UI for this https://jsfiddle.net/d176L8x3/

HTML

```
<div id="accordion">

    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit? </h3> 
    <div class="answer">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
    </div>

    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit? </h3> 
    <div class="answer">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
    </div>

    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit? </h3> 
    <div class="answer">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
    </div>

    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit? </h3> 
    <div class="answer">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
    </div>

</div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
  $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
});
```

Read more HERE https://jqueryui.com/accordion/#default

Answer (score 0):

here butt is button id and 1A is answer div id

```
$("#butt").on('click', function (e) {

   $("#1A").toggle();

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8tn9h5cu/3/

Answer (score 0):

check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/exuj09bn/3/) on JSfiddler

Added text in case of up & down button. like below

```
<i class="fa fa-angle-up">imgup</i>                 
<i class="fa fa-angle-down">imgdown</i>
```

Answer (score -1):

Do like this.

```
<div class="answer_visible">
  <div type="button" class="q_button" data-id="firstdiv1" onclick="showanswer(this)">
     <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit? </span> 
     <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>                 
     <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>                   
  </div>
  <div class="answer" id="firstdiv1">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
  </div>
```

Here is javascript code

```
funtion showanswer(element){
var id=$(element).attr('data-id');
$('#'+id).toggle();

 }
```